# how to covert oracle string with spaces in between chars to teradata as we are getting casting error?

Tags: sql, teradata, etl

We are migrating data from oracle to teradata 16.2.
We have a string field contains customer ID (text type) with spaces in between for example:

```
343  2224 S, 5434443 X, 5434 3434 T....
```

When trying to migrate this to teradata we are getting a casting error.
how can we resolve it?
php conversion function can be also a solution if there is nothing else recommended.

Comment: Can you add your code which is giving you this problem.  Also if you are getting an error - include the message text and indicate which line is causing this error.

Comment: Why do you think that you get the error because of the spaces? Which type are you trying to cast to?

Comment: Convert it to _what_? Pretend that we have no idea what "teradata" is or what format it wants data in. [because we don't]

Comment: we tested it and instead of putting into the teradata DB the entries with spaces we put dummy data with no spaces and we got no casting error. So it must be something when trying to migrate the oracle data to teradata. the field is configured as text but it is a strong of chars including spaces. We have 1 same column on the source side and one of the target side. when mapping and trying to migrate the data to the target we are getting casting error and for sure it is something with the spaces. it might be that teradata DB dont know how to handle spaces in a varchar.

Comment: Teradata could care less about spaces in character fields. You need to give us a lot more information.  How is the column defined in Oracle? How is the column defined in Teradata?  How are you actually loading the data to Teradata?

Comment: There's no problem with embedded spaces in a VarChar in Teradata. What exact error message do you get? Maybe it's not a space but an error character: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character

Comment: Here is the error we are getting. SQL Error (22005) [Teradata][Support] (40550) Invalid character value for cast specification. // on the

Comment: So that means you have hidden characters in there, not white space.

Comment: on oracle side it is defined as text and on teradata as varchar(50). Is there any way to add here the full log as looks like the is a characters limit here

Comment: ok what does it mean "hidden characters" and how can we solve it?

Comment: This is an ODBC error about bind values, try to cast to a varchar in Oracle. Or maybe it's a wrong character set...

Comment: Well, we cannot touch the source data so we will need to write a php function to receive the data and cast it. any idea how to write this function in php?

Comment: How do you extract the source data from Oracle?